# What does this format do in CSS: p[class|=abc]?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What does this format do in CSS:

```
p[class|=abc]
```

and

```
#pTag a[href^="https://"]
```

I'm not able to search for it as I don't know the exact terminology for this.

Any help with some links to study on these square brackets thing would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The syntax that comes before each set of `{}` is called a selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are [Attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors). Read the link for more information.

Please note that the last CSS example is a CSS3 selector.

Answer (score 1):

[Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

> E[lang|="en"] Matches any E element
>   whose "lang" attribute has a
>   hyphen-separated list of values
>   beginning (from the left) with "en".

.

> [att^=val]
>       Represents an element with the att attribute whose value begins with the
>   prefix "val". If "val" is the empty
>   string then the selector does not
>   represent anything.

Answer (score 1):

**Hyphen [|=] Attribute Selector:**

The hyphen (-) is used primarily as a delimiter for language codes.

```
<style>
    .test        { display:none; }
    [lang|="en"] { display:block; }
</style>

<div class="test" lang="en-us">Test for [|=] (Hyphen) succeeded.</div>
```

**Prefix [^=] Attribute Selector:**

```
<style>
    .test       { display:none; }
    [attr^="B"] { display:block; }
</style>

<div class="test" attr="Blue">Test for [^=] (Prefix) succeeded.</div>
```